# Unity: Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details

Tags: android, facebook, compilation, unity-game-engine, native

Since I have installed this asset: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/10825 I can no longer build my project for android. I have no idea what is causing this problem and how I can fix this. Here is the full error:

> Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
>   -bootclasspath "C:/Users/Stefan/Desktop/android-sdk-windows/platforms/android-14\android.jar" -d "C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\Apps\My Game\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding ascii "com\facebook\android\Manifest.java" "com\facebook\android\R.java" "com\StefanApps\MyGame\Manifest.java" "com\StefanApps\MyGame\R.java"
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
>
> UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

What could be causing this and how could this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Check the path for "javac.exe", I bet there's no such file there. It seems that installing JRE 6 32-bit (even on 64-bit system!) fixes this issue.

You can grab it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR